# FindBugs Maven Plugin in integration test module

Tags: wso2, findbugs

I am working on writing test cases in Java. I would like to integrate FindBugs Maven Plugin to enhance my code quality in test classes. I have added FindBugs Maven Plugin to POM file of the test module. I can successfully create FindBugs XML document but build succeeds even FindBugs found some bugs in my code.

Can anyone please guide me on this?

My configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <effort>Max</effort>
        <threshold>Low</threshold>
        <xmlOutput>true</xmlOutput>
        <findbugsXmlOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/findbugs</findbugsXmlOutputDirectory>
        <includeTests>true</includeTests>
        <failOnError>true</failOnError>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>analyze-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FindBugs Maven Plugin behaves differently depending whether `src/main/java` is empty or not. If it doesn't exist (module is test-only and contains only `src/test/java`) build is not failing:

```
[INFO] --- findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.3:findbugs (findbugs) @ findbugs-fail-build ---
[INFO] Fork Value is true
     [java] Warnings generated: 1
[INFO] Done FindBugs Analysis....
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.3:check (findbugs) < :findbugs @ findbugs-fail-build <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.3:check (findbugs) @ findbugs-fail-build ---

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When there is some production code in module (`src/main/java` not empty) the build fails:

```
[INFO] --- findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.3:findbugs (findbugs) @ findbugs-fail-build ---
[INFO] Fork Value is true
     [java] Warnings generated: 1
[INFO] Done FindBugs Analysis....
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.3:check (findbugs) < :findbugs @ findbugs-fail-build <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- findbugs-maven-plugin:3.0.3:check (findbugs) @ findbugs-fail-build ---
[INFO] BugInstance size is 1
[INFO] Error size is 0
[INFO] Total bugs: 1
[INFO] Private method io.github.mkordas.ClassWithFindBugsViolationInTest.unusedPrivateMethod() is never called [io.github.mkordas.ClassWithFindBugsViolationInTest] At ClassWithFindBugsViolationInTest.java:[line 5] UPM_UNCALLED_PRIVATE_METHOD
[INFO] 
To see bug detail using the Findbugs GUI, use the following command "mvn findbugs:gui"
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

It is **bug** in FindBugs Maven Plugin. I've reported it as [gleclaire/findbugs-maven-plugin#33](https://github.com/gleclaire/findbugs-maven-plugin/issues/33). In [FindbugsViolationCheckMojo](https://github.com/gleclaire/findbugs-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/mojo/findbugs/FindbugsViolationCheckMojo.groovy#L478) there's an if checking whether 'main' classes exist and if not, plugin assumes that there was nothing analyzed and code to fail the build is not invoked.

There are two workarounds:

- add
  `<classFilesDirectory>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</classFilesDirectory>`
  to configuration
- add any code to `src/main/java`

Comment: I have added the maven phase as you suggested But still I cannot get tests fail. please can you help me?

Comment: @satkunamrajeenthini please see sample project with failing build on violations in test code: https://github.com/mkordas/findbugs-fail-build
Do you do anything differently?

Comment: @satkunamrajeenthini please see updated answer, does it resolve your issue?

Comment: I can get build failure when I have added some java class files to directory src/main/java . But it is not actually necessary to add those java files since I don't have any production code. I am only working with test. Is there any way to overcome this issue?

Comment: @satkunamrajeenthini yes, please see updated anwer and accept it if the workaround helps in your case